# Cannot log in with default user on Mac 10.10

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, logins, mac-os-x

I am running PostgreSQL on a Mac 10.10

> PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn), 64-bit

I am having trouble connecting to the *_postgres* Mac account. As far as I remember, the under Mac created account is not *postgres* but *_postgres*. I want to log in as that account to access Postgres and create a new role/database for some user on the system.

```
sudo -u _postgres psql
```

Throws me this:

> psql: FATAL:  role "_postgres" does not exist

While:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

gives me this:

> sudo: unknown user: postgres

So, how to login as the default Postgres user?!

Answer (score 2):

Just try your normal user account. 
`bash# psql postgres`. 
Depending on how you installed PostgreSQL (homebrew, ports or Postgres.app) the default account is set to your account instead of a seperate one. Beside this, consider to update to 9.3.11